# What is difference between routing and RESTFul service

Tags: rest, routes

They both sound the same, basically a "protocol" for creating your URLs.

That is they are sort of descriptive URLs rather than URLs that specify an html file explicitly.

Is routing and RESTFul service (URLs) basically the same thing or are they different?